# Escape chars with grep wihtin a loop in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, grep

I can run the following code without a problem:

```
echo topic = "def";ghi | grep -oP "(?<=topic = \").+?(?=\"";ghi)
```

But if I put it in a for loop in a .bat file, it no longer works.

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in (urls.txt) do (
echo topic = "def";ghi | grep -oP "(?<=topic = \").+?(?=\"";ghi) 
)
```

The error says `.+?(? was unexpected at this time`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the first `)` in your `grep` statement is closing the `for` code block.  You either need to include your entire `grep` argument in quotes, or escape whatever parentheses aren't quoted with a caret.

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in (urls.txt) do (
    echo topic = "def";ghi | grep -oP "(?<=topic = \"^).+?^(?=\"";ghi^) 
)
```

I think that's right anyway.  It might require a little trial and error.  But whenever you need to escape a special character in a batch script, use a `^`.